# Overlapping instances - how to circumvent them

Tags: haskell

I am a beginner at Haskell, so please be indulgent. For reasons that are not important here, I am trying to define a operator `<^>` that takes a function and an argument and returns the value of the function by the argument, *irrespective of which of the function and the argument came first*. In short, I would like to be able to write the following:

```
foo :: Int -> Int
foo x = x * x

arg :: Int
arg = 2

foo <^> arg -- valid, returns 4
arg <^> foo -- valid, returns 4
```

I have tried to accomplish that through type families, as follows:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances, MultiParamTypeClasses, TypeFamilies, TypeOperators #-}

class Combine t1 t2 where
    type Output t1 t2 :: *
    (<^>) :: t1 -> t2 -> Output t1 t2

instance Combine (a->b) a where
    type Output (a->b) a = b
    f <^> x = f x

instance Combine a (a->b) where
    type Output a a->b = b
    x <^> f = f x
```

On this code, GHC throws a `Conflicting family instance declarations`. My guess is that the overlap GHC complains about occurs when type `a->b` and type `a` are the same. I don't know Haskell well enough, but I suspect that with recursive type definitions, one may be able to construct such a situation. I have a couple of questions:

- Since this is a rather remote scenario that will never occur in my application (in particular not with *foo* and *arg* above), I was wondering if there was a way of specifying a dummy default instance to use in case of overlap? I have tried the different `OVERLAPS` and `OVERLAPPING` flags, but they didn't have any effect.
- If not, is there a better way of achieving what I want?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think your class makes sense. `const id` and `id const` are both valid code, so what would `const <^> id` do?

Comment: wrt your "reasons that are not important", there's a serious use case here: some people want to use `(.)` operator for postfix function apply, as in most OOP. But there's too much legacy code using it as compose. Can we do both, by looking at the types of the arguments to `(.)`? There's still the `const.id` problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bad idea, in my view, but I'll play along.

A possible solution is to switch to functional dependencies. Usually I tend to avoid fundeps in favor of type families, but here they make the instances compile in a simple way.

```
class Combine t1 t2 r | t1 t2 -> r where
    (<^>) :: t1 -> t2 -> r

instance Combine (a->b) a b where
    f <^> x = f x

instance Combine a (a->b) b where
    x <^> f = f x
```

Note that this class will likely cause problems during type inference if we use polymorphic functions. This is because, with polymorphic functions, the code can easily become ambiguous.

For instance `id <^> id` could pick any of the two instances. Above, melpomene already reported `const <^> id` being ambiguous as well.

---

The following is weakly related, but I want to share it anyway:

What about type families instead? I tried to experiment a bit, and I just discovered a limitation which I did not know. Consider the closed type family

```
type family Output a b where
   Output (a->b) a = b
   Output a (a->b) = b
```

The code above compiles, but then the type `Output a (a->b)` is stuck. The second equation does not get applied, as if the first one could potentially match.

Usually, I can understand this in some other scenarios, but here unifying

```
Output (a' -> b') b' ~ Output a (a -> b)
```

seems to fail since we would need `a ~ (a' -> b') ~ (a' -> a -> b)` which is impossible,  with finite types. For some reason, GHC does not use this argument (does it pretend infinite types exist in this check? why?)

Anyway, this makes replacing fundeps with type families harder than it could be, it seems. I have no idea about why GHC accepts the fundeps code I posted, yet refuses the OP's code which is essentially the same thing, except using type families.

Comment: Reliably excluding infinite types turns out to be rather tricky in the presence of type families. `type family Oops where Oops = () ': Oops`.

Comment: @dfeuer True, but in the unification problem above I think we have `a'->b'  ~ a , b'~a -> b` which involves no type families. I guess it was simpler to simply turn off the occurs check in all the cases, rather than only when type families are still involved.

Comment: @chi Is `b' ~ a'; b ~ a'` not a valid solution?

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply, chi! My application doesn't involve polymorphic functions so this problem won't arise, although I recognize that this is anissue in the long run. I tried type families as well and run in the same problem you describe. I could solve it by adding a constraint like `(Output (a->b) a ~ b)`, but this leads to some unwanted code duplication and, I suspect, more problems down the road.

Comment: @HTNW No, since with your substitution the first constraint becomes `(a'->a') ~ a` which is not generally true.

Comment: @chi, I believe the occurs check is still around. But GHC doesn't want to reduce things any more than necessary.

Comment: "My application doesn't involve polymorphic functions". GHC doesn't know that, and certainly can't tell if your class/method might get exported to somewhere else that is polymorphic. If you're going to use fancy generic instances like that, always expect the worst.

Answer (score 1):

@chi is close; an approach using either FunDeps or Closed Type Families is possible. But the `Combine` instances are potentially ambiguous/unifiable just as much as the CTF `Output` equations.

When chi says the FunDep code is accepted, that's only half-true: GHC plain leads you down the garden path. It will accept the instances but then you find you can't use them/you get weird error messages. See the Users Guide at "potential for overlap".

If you're looking to resolve a potentially ambiguous `Combine` constraint, you might get an error suggesting you try `IncoherentInstances` (or `INCOHERENT` pragma). Don't do that. You have a genuinely incoherent problem; all that will do is defer the problem to somewhere else. It's always possible to avoid `Incoherent` -- providing you can rejig your instances (as follows) and they're not locked away in libraries.

Notice that because of the potential ambiguity, another Haskell compiler (Hugs) doesn't let you write `Combine` like that. It has a more correct implementation of Haskell's (not-well-stated) rules.

The answer is to use a sort of overlap where one instance is strictly more specific. You must first decide which you way you want to prefer in case of ambiguity. I'll choose function prefixed to argument:

```
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances, TypeFamilies #-}

instance {-# OVERLAPPING #-} (r ~ b)
         => Combine (a->b) a r  where ...

instance {-# OVERLAPPABLE #-} (Combine2 t1 t2 r)
         => Combine t1 t2 r  where
  (<^>) = revApp

class Combine2 t1 t2 r  | t1 t2 -> r  where
  revApp :: t1 -> t2 -> r

instance (b ~ r) => Combine2 a (a->b) r  where
  revApp x f = f x
```

Notice that the `OVERLAPPABLE` instance for `Combine` has bare tyvars, it's a catch-all so it's always matchable. All the compiler has to do is decide whether some wanted constraint is of the form of the `OVERLAPPING` instance.

The `Combine2` constraint on the `OVERLAPPABLE` instance is no smaller than the head, so you need `UndecidableInstances`. Also beware that deferring to `Combine2` will mean that if the compiler still can't resolve, you're likely to get puzzling error messages.

Talking of bare tyvars/"always matchable", I've used an additional trick to make the compiler work really hard to improve the types: There's bare `r` in the head of the instance, with an Equality type improvement constraint `(b ~ r) =>`. To use the `~`, you need to switch on `TypeFamilies` even though you're not writing any type families.

A CTF approach would be similar. You need a catch-all equation on `Output` that calls an auxiliary type function. Again you need `UndecidableInstances`.